# Word opening Hyperlinks with wrong PDF Viewer

Tags: microsoft-word, adobe-reader

I have a user who is trying to create a procedure document and is hyperlinking a couple PDFs in the Word doc. Clicking on the hyperlinks opens to documents in Adobe Reader DC, even if the user has their default set to PDF Xchange Editor. Any PDF opened any other way opens with Xchange, only in Word does it open in Adobe.

Is there a specific setting for Word to change the default PDF app?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A file-type in Windows may have a default handler for several actions.
Two of these actions are Open and Edit.

It seems as if, for that user, the Edit action specifies Adobe Reader DC,
while the Open action specifies Xchange.

As Word is an editor and not a viewer, clicking a hyperlink to a PDF
uses the Edit action instead of Open. This shouldn't normally happen,
but your user may have a non-standard setup.

Comment: Cool mr harrymc.  Better answer than mine! :)  You are the guy I love to hate.. or is it hate to love.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: I would prefer an third option in addition to your two.

Comment: But is there a way to force Word to open .pdf hyperlinks with the "Open" action instead of the "Edit" action?

Comment: @mivk: I don't know of any such method.

Answer (score 0):

You do this in the operation system, not Word.  Harrymc makes some really good points that I didn't think of. :)

Word uses a simple Windows function called `ShellExecuteEx(...)` that used to be a simple call to `ShellExecute(...)` (similar but with less options). (addition) but this function uses something called a VERB (like open, edit, print).  Read harrymc post for this.

My guess is that it is possible that they are using the online version of word?  In this case, see [this](https://www.lifewire.com/prevent-adobe-from-opening-pdfs-in-ie-153338).  It will tell you how to disable adobe as the default in the browser.

Although ShellExecute() uses the preferences of the operating system (and in turn, the user themselves) to decide what program opens what, when opening things from the browser, all bets are off.  Especially if there is something like the Adobe "wonderful software" plugin installed.

More than anything else, I would suggest simply uninstalling everything Acrobat and Adobe as a whole if they aren't REALLY using it.